# How to create 2D textures from footage?

Tags: textures, animation, mobile, video

I am new to game development but I heard, that already in the 80s with Prince of Persia, indie developers where capable to create textures from footage. I am developing a game and so far I get an illustrator to draw things I need.

I'd like to explore the opportunity of taking some video footage of complex movements and create some basic textures from it (as I guess [Jordan Mechner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_Mechner) did), so to then "feed" them to a more digital artist to draw "over" them in order to make them cartoonish and coherent with the style of the pre-existing in the game.

Anyone of you could also explore the answer for mobile game development? Any crazy mobile developer that did so already for a 2D game? :)

Comment: I think my answer [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/35561/how-to-i-teach-my-artist-to-do-arts-for-games/35569#35569) could be useful for this too. Particularly the frame by frame sections.

Answer (score 1):

The technique is called [rotoscoping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotoscoping). It does lead to very fluid movement. Yes, you could use it for any game platform (in theory), but to get the full benefit of the style it's best used with a *lot* of frames.