# Are there tools available for building hierarchical sprite-based objects in games like Vector Man or Gunstar Heroes?

Tags: animation, sprites, tools, editors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tools for 2D skeletal animation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22000/tools-for-2d-skeletal-animation)

I'm looking for a tool that would let me build multi-part sprite objects of the kind you can find in Sega Genesis games like Vector Man and bosses like Gunstar Heroes. Not only are they built with multiple sprites, but they're animated on a kind of really basic skeletal model.

Are there any tools out there that builds that sort of thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "build"? For what would they be built?

Comment: I think what tech do I use questions are discouraged by the FAQ http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq.

Comment: @GameDev-er This question belongs to a different category altogether, which is: "I want to do this thing, is there anything available for it?" It's very different to "which tech do I use?" Answers to "which tech?" questions are normally extremely localised to that specific person and generally completely irrelevant to everyone else (including that the answer is very often "whatever you want"). This kind of question, on the other hand, is _really useful_ for _everyone else_ looking to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks jhonathan. I can't undo my vote down though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check Spriter: http://www.brashmonkey.com/spriter.htm

Comment: Works for me. I also found Skeleton 1.1 by Nick Koza.